# Get count of c for each b found in another table

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables.
table_1 consists of a, b (primary key for identifying the email sent), and s.
table_2 table consists of a, b (primary key for identifying the email clicked), and c.

For each table_1.a, I want to get the count of table_2.c for each b of table_1 found in table_2. If b from table_1 is not found in table_2, then the count of c for that b is set to 0. Then, for each table_1.a, I want to order each b by s.
Example:

```
table_1 =                           
+----------+----+----------+
|         a|   b|         s|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1433| 42a|2021-02-01|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1523| 41c|2021-02-23|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1523| 42c|2021-02-24|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1523| 38a|2021-01-03|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1421| 39a|2021-02-28|
+----------+----+----------+

mclicks =
+----------+----+----------+
|         a|   b|         c|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1523| 41c|2021-02-24|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1523| 41c|2021-02-25|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1523| 42c|2021-02-27|
+----------+----+----------+
|      1421| 39a|2021-02-28|
+----------+----+----------+
```

I would like my final output to be:

```
+----+----+-----+
|  a1|   b|    c|
+----+----+-----+
|1433| 42a|    0|
+----+----+-----+
|1523| 38a|    0|
+----+----+-----+
|1523| 41c|    2|
+----+----+-----+
|1523| 42c|    1|
+----+----+-----+
```

This is my code:

```
df = table_1.join(table_2, table_1.a == table_2.a, "left") \
            .select(table_1.a.alias('a1'), table_1.s.alias('s1'), \
                    table_1.b.alias('b1'), table_2.c('c2')) \
            .filter((table_1.s).between('2021-01-31', '2021-03-01'))

df1 = df.groupBy(df['a1'], df['b1'], df['s1']) \
        .agg(count(df['c2']).alias('df_cd'))

w = Window.partitionBy(df1['a1'], df1['b1']) \
          .orderBy(df1['s1'])

df2 = df1.withColumn('row', row_number().over(w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Join, conditionally attribute c and groupby, sum

```
table_1 = (table_1.join(mclicks, how='outer', on=['a','b']).withColumn("c1",F.when(F.col("c").isNotNull(), 1).otherwise(0)
)).groupby('a','b').agg(sum(col('c1')).alias('c'))
```